# how to parse internal json ojbects separatly

Tags: android, json

How to parse json array which contain multiple arrays> I have added a structure below.I need to parse separately category object.There are two category object(XYZ,XYZ2)

```
{
  "ABC-BH":[
    {
      "category":"XYZ",
      "category_ch":"Main",
      "pdfs":[

      ],
      "thumbs":[

      ],
      "previews":[

      ],
      "url":"http://abc/list/20141219/"
    },
    {
      "category":"XYZ2",
      "category_ch":"Newsweek",
      "pdfs":[

      ],
      "thumbs":[

      ],
      "previews":[

      ],
      "url":"http://abc/list/20141219/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Gson, it is a library from Google which encapsulates JSON parsing in an easy way.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

You need to create model classes but parsing is quite simple:

```
 YourClass theClass = gson.fromJson(stringJSON, YourClass.class);
```

You can find information in the link above.